# CORDOVA IOS RUN APP THAT IS INSIDE ANOTHER

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an ios cordova app that inside the app.js should launch another app that is downloaded and unzipped inside the documents folder of the main app.
Inside cordova.file.documentsDirectory there is a folder zipContent that
contains 3 cordova base apps (app1 - app2 - app3) each app only do an alert
with its name.
How can i "exec" the app1 (or 2 or 3) from the documents/zipContent folder
from the main app?
This is the schema of the app:

    `MAIN APP:
    ->launcher (app.js)
    ->documents (folder)
      ->zipContent (folder)
        ->app1 (cordova folder app)
        ->app2 (cordova folder app)
        ->app3 (cordova folder app)`